netty internal error occurred when java17+spring boot3.02+spring cloud gateway was used
siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000009300000092
Register to memory mapping
RAX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb, SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb0294f200f]
hs_err_pid
